# Custom key that alternates between Home and End

Tags: keyboard, macbook, capslock

I recently purchased a Macbook Pro and found out that I really miss the Home and End keys found on full keyboards. I know that you can press fn+left/dn+right for home and end but it simply isn't practical and not very quick, especially given how tiny the left and right keys are.
So I was looking at a way to make them go elsewhere. I thought about the "eject disc" button, but I already mapped that to the "Delete" command which I missed even more. There's still the Caps Lock key, sitting there unmapped, easy to reach, and very large and accessible, seems perfect! Only, it's one key and I'd like two. So I thought "How about making this key acts as "Home" key when the cursor is at the end of a line, but as "End" key otherwise?" This feels like an acceptable compromise. Is there any way to do so? I'd like a way to do that on Linux, but I appreciate answers that work regardless of the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't impossible, but it'd be a pain, and i doubt any tools for this exist.  I'm 95% positive that the behavior you're after can't be achieved by keybindings alone: you'd need to write a program that captures keyboard input, and then inspects the state of the typing area you're in, and then sends either "Home" or "End".  This is certainly doable, but i'm not sure it's worth the effort.